# Overriding System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine to log to a file

Tags: vb.net, oop, logging, trace, diagnostics

This may be more of an OOP concept question, but here's what I'd like to do.

I have an application that outputs debug information using System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine so it can be viewed with DebugView.

I'd like to override/extend (not sure of the proper terminology) this method to log the text to a file instead, or maybe in addition to the Trace output. This would allow me to write a new WriteLine method for my app, and I could leave all my other System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine statements unchanged throughout the rest of the application.

So how would I go about changing the behavior of this method within my VB.Net app?

Comment: any final solution ? there are 2 answers, not accepted...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Are you absolutely committed to still using Trace? If not, I'd use a more fully-featured logging system such as [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html).

However, if you really want to use `Trace` then you can reconfigure the `TraceListener`s used with an `app.config` file. The [`TraceListener` MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) give an example somewhat like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="fileLogger" 
             type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
             initializeData="LogFile.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

[`TextWriterTraceListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.aspx) will dump logs to the given file. (There are other options available too.)

Alternatively, you can do this programmatically:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("foo.log"));
```

Note that you may need to explicitly flush the traces before your app exits, either with:

```
Trace.Flush();
```

or the more complicated:

```
foreach (TraceListener listener in Trace.Listeners)
{
    listener.Flush();
}
```

(I only mention it because I had to when testing this!)

EDIT: As noted in comments, if you're happy for the listener to be flushed after *every* write (which avoids having to flush at the end, but may harm performance) you can set [`Trace.AutoFlush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.autoflush.aspx) to true (including in the XML - see the `autoflush` attribute).

Comment: Isn't the iteration over the listeners + Flush equivalent to calling the static method Trace.Flush() ? 
Also, do you know how the client application can ensure that listeners are properly disposed?

Comment: You may well be right about Trace.Flush - not sure. As for disposing of the listeners - I'd hope that listeners don't need to be disposed in order to write their data.

Comment: Yup, Trace.Flush does the required business. Edited answer appropriately.

Comment: Yes, I was just wandering if it's the client's responsibility to dispose them. I'm trying to write a custom listener and some points are quite unclear (e.g. dispose never gets called).

Comment: I'd try to write the listener such that it doesn't matter - I think it's highly likely that you won't be disposed. Try not to rely on finalization either. That makes life somewhat harder, but there we go :( You might be able to listen to application termination (or AppDomain unloading) events and release resources then - but you should make sure that your listener doesn't die if it's then called after its own disposal!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments :) I think I'll try to follow the pattern "do your best to cleanup and hope that the client behaves properly". I think in most cases autoflush will be set to true anyway.

Comment: Instead of flushing manually, you can simply `Trace.AutoFlush = true;`

Answer (score 3):

There is a TextWriterTraceListener which you can configure to output the trace log to a file.  Configuration information can be found on the MSDN here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener(VS.80).aspx

You can also dump to the event log or a variety of other places for a list of built in trace listeners you can look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7(VS.80).aspx