# C# `Trace.WriteLine` to print to file only that temporarily skips console ouput print

Tags: c#, logging, command-line

As we discussed here, we can use `Trace.WriteLine` to write logs to both command-line console and a chosen file.

My need is to sometimes use `Trace.WriteLine` to **print ONLY to file, NOT to console.**

How can we reach that?

p.s.

Here is how I init the listener

```
#region init logging
Trace.Listeners.Clear();

var logFile = Path.Combine("Path", "to", "log file");
var twtl = new TextWriterTraceListener(logFile);
twtl.Name = "TextLogger";
twtl.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.ThreadId | TraceOptions.DateTime;
var ctl = new ConsoleTraceListener(false);
ctl.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.DateTime;

Trace.Listeners.Add(twtl);
Trace.Listeners.Add(ctl);
Trace.AutoFlush = true;

//Trace.WriteLine("The first line to be in the logfile and on the console.");
#endregion
```

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870634/overriding-system-diagnostics-trace-writeline-to-log-to-a-file)

Comment: How do you configured listeners? can you share some more details around?

Comment: @HariPrasad I have updated my OP to add the initial codes

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado How would we get the point of `temporarily/sometimes`?

Comment: It will not answer your question but why you don't use [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/)?

Comment: @onestarblack I'll take `log4net` into second choice; I prefer the 1st one to be built-in logging in C#