# Change where Trace.WriteLine() is sent in a console application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application that uses an assembly that I cannot modify. Said assembly has a conditional define to output debug data via `Trace.WriteLine()` when the configuration of the application is **Debug**.

Now in my console application this means that I get heaps of data output to the console window which I don't want.

So is there anything I can do in my console application (I still want to build and run it with **Debug** configuration) so that I can redirect the output of those `Trace.WriteLine()` elsewhere when running with a **Debug** configuration? Say to a text file?

Comment: What's that "ASP.NET 4.x" at the beginning of the question meant to represent? How is it relevant?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto meant to say .NET not ASP.NET and indicates that I am not running .NET Core

Comment: [tag:.net] => .NET Framework. [tag:.net-core] => .NET Core. That's what tags are for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine to log to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870634/overriding-system-diagnostics-trace-writeline-to-log-to-a-file)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks. Good to know that versions of things are not important anymore.